# Sumar en un campo si hago clic en otro campo

Tags: javascript, jquery

Busco una función que me permita sumar 1 en el campo "Número de reagendas" en caso de que previamente haya hecho seleccionado reagendar en el desplegable.
Gracias!

```html
<label for="pais">Acción</label>
              <select id="cmb3" name="cmb3" required="required">
                                    <option value="">Selecciona...></option>                                   
                                    <option value="CONTESTAR">Contestar</option>
                                    <option value="REAGENDAR">Reagendar</option>
                                </select>
<br><br>
      
              <label class="elq-label " for="fe694">Numero de reagendas
              </label>
            
                    <input type="number" name="009002010" id="fe694" value="" style="width:50%;">
```

Comment: Qué has intentado? El campo de reagendas deberia ser type number, no text

Comment: Genial, mil gracias. No he intentado nada de momento porque estoy perdida con el sumatorio. No sé cómo empezar.

Comment: Que te permita sumar 1 dónde?? Si poner el campo tipo número como dice @angogi te aparece el spinner de números y con las flechas puedes aumentar o disminuir. Explica mejor que necesitas

Answer (score 1):

Para incrementar dinámicamente el Número de reagendas debes agregar el siguiente script e incluir un evento onchange en el select.

Lo que hace es escuchar un cambio en el selector, de manera que al ser cambiado se llama a la función sumar(), en esta función se comprueba que el valor seleccionado sea 'Reagendar' y de ser así se incrementa el contador.

```js
function sumar() {
  var caja = document.getElementById("fe694");
  var selector = document.getElementById("cmb3");
  if (selector.value.toLowerCase() != 'reagendar') {
      return false;
  }
  if (caja.value == '') caja.value = 0;
  caja.value = parseInt(caja.value) + 1;
  selector.value = ""
}
```

```html
<label for="pais">Acción</label>
<select id="cmb3" name="cmb3" onchange="sumar()" required="required">
  <option value="">Selecciona...></option>                                   
  <option value="CONTESTAR">Contestar</option>
  <option value="REAGENDAR">Reagendar</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label class="elq-label " for="fe694">Numero de reagendas</label>
<input type="number" name="009002010" id="fe694" value="" style="width:50%;">
```

Espero que haya servido de ayuda.

Comment: Si pones tu código en un snippet (fragmento de código) quedaría mejor, así se puede probar que funciona.

Comment: Gracias por el consejo, saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido más o menos. Lo que buscaba era que la primera vez que doy a reagendar se ponga 1, pero cuando lo cierro y lo vuelvo a abrir la siguiente vez, y haga clic en reagendar, me ponga 2. Es decir, que lo recuerde y le vaya sumando uno cada vez.

Comment: Disculpa si se ha sentido molesto, he intentado contactar con usted pero tengo cierta prisa, si hubiera encontrado una forma mejor de contactarle lo hubiera hecho. Me ha sido de gran ayuda. Pero no! El código que uso es muy largo, nadie me hace los deberes! Gracias

Comment: @r4ziel me ayudarías a poner el código de manera que sea todo el javascript igual pero añadir una funcion de "y si no es reagendar (es porque es contestar) siempre 0"?