# Como sumar progresivamente o restar el resultado de un input

Tags: javascript

estoy haciendo una suma en función de si clico "reagendar en el select". Pero solo consigo poner un 1. Y quiero que se recuerde el numero cuando vuelva a abrir el formulario y si vuelvo a reagendar que se sume 1 más.
gracias!!

```html
<label for="pais">Acción</label>
<select id="cmb3" name="cmb3" onchange="sumar()" required="required">
  <option value="">Selecciona...></option>                                   
  <option value="CONTESTAR">Contestar</option>
  <option value="REAGENDAR">Reagendar</option>
</select>
<br><br>
<label class="elq-label " for="fe694">Numero de reagendas</label>
<input type="number" name="009002010" id="fe694" value="" style="width:50%;">
<script>
  function sumar() {
  var caja = document.getElementById("fe694");
  if (document.getElementById("cmb3").value.toLowerCase() != 'reagendar') {
    return false;
  }
  if (caja.value == '') caja.value = 0;
  caja.value = parseInt(caja.value) + 1;
}
</script>
```

Comment: ¿Responde esto a tu pregunta? [Sumar en un campo si hago clic en otro campo](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/364136/sumar-en-un-campo-si-hago-clic-en-otro-campo)

Answer (score 2):

Supongo que necesites almacenamiento y no tienes una base de datos, puedes utilizar el localStorage o el session storage, yo tengo un proyecto funcionando que guarda las ultimas opciones que selecciona el usuario en un formulario.

Este es una forma de almacenar y obtener un valor.

Asi almaceno el valor (`numero` es el valor a almacenar y `'reagendar'` la llave para luego buscar el valor).

```
window.localStorage.setItem('reagendar', numero);
```

Asi obtengo el valor almacenado

```
let reagendar = window.localStorage.getItem('reagendar');
```

la diferecia de este localStorage con el sessionStorage es que el sessionStorage se elimina cuando se cierra el navegador y el localStorage permanece.

OJO: este metodo no es recomendado cuando estas almacenando informacion sensible ya que se puede modificar facilmente desde el navegador.

También en caso de ser un objeto como es mi caso lo trabajas como json, luego lo llevas a string y lo almacenas y haces el proceso inverso y tienes tú objeto nuevamente.